# SPSS value labels as column names for tables in R?

Tags: r, spss

I'm reading a .sav file using *haven*:

```
library(haven)
data <- read_spss("file.sav", user_na = FALSE)
```

Then trying to display one of the variables in a table:

```
table(data$region)
```

Which returns:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
 85 208  43 171  30  40  95 310 133  29  77  36
```

Which is technically correct, however - in SPSS, the numerical values in the top row have labels associated with them (region names in this case). If I just run `data$region`, it shows me the numbers and their associated labels at the end of the output, but is there a way to make those string labels appear in the first table row instead of their numerical counterparts?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can check `attributes(data$region)` or `attr(data$region, "label")`  Your example is not reproducible.  Please use `dput` to show example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to cast the variable as a factor, using the "labels" attribute of the vector as the factor levels.  The sjlabelled package includes a function that does this in one step:

```
data$region <- sjlabelled::as_label(data$region)
```

While the table command will still work on the resulting data, the layout may be a little messy.  The forcats package has a function that pretty-prints frequency tables for factors:

```
data$region %>% forcats::fct_count()
```